# Net Module Nodester not Listening to Port

Tags: sockets, node.js, nodester

I have a basic node.js app that is designed to open up a connection between two clients and echo the input of one to the other.

```
var net = require("net");
console.log("Relay Started");
var id = 0;
var Socket = [];
relay = net.createServer(function(socket) {
        socket.on('connect', function() {
                console.log('Connected');
                if(socket.id==null) {
                        socket.id = id;
                        Socket[id]=socket;
                        id++;
                }
        });
        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            data = data.toString()
            if (socket.id==0) {
                    Socket[1].write(data);
            } else if (socket.id==1) {
                    Socket[0].write(data);
            }
            console.log(socket);
            console.log(data.toString());
    });

})
relay.listen(process.env['app_port']||8080);
```

It works fine when run locally, however when I put it onto a Nodester development server, I am unable to connect by using `telnet zapcs.nodester.com 18007` (it is hosted under the name zapcs, and the given port is 18007). The `Relay Started` is logged, but nothing after that, and no connection. Any ideas on why this would be?

~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not `telnet zapcs.nodester.com 18007`, you only can connect to zapcs.nodester.com:80 by http or websock, nodester will route your request to your app actual port (18007) on the host.

And check this: http://www.slideshare.net/cmatthieu/nodester-architecture-overview-roadmap-9382423